# LED matrix incorrectly displays data from structures

Tags: c++, avr, attiny

I just started to work with LED matrix (16*16) and attiny85.

The current purpose is to switch on a led on each row, where led number is the number of row (I know that led strip is like a snake, it does not matter for now).

So, I written an `byte matrix[16][16]` and manually put a digit into target cells. It worked well. After that I replace `byte matrix[16][16]` into a `rgb matrix[16][16]` where `struct rgb {byte r, byte g, byte b}` and it doesn`t work correctly (see photos below).

The LED functions:

```
#define LED PB0
#define byte unsigned char

struct rgb {
    byte r;
    byte g;
    byte b;
};

// @see https://agelectronica.lat/pdfs/textos/L/LDWS2812.PDF
// HIGH 0.8mks +/- 150ns and 0.45mks +/- 150ns
// LOW 0.4mks +/- 150ns and 0.85mks +/- 150ns
// 1s/8000000 = 125ns for 1 tact

void setBitHigh(byte pin) {
    PORTB |= _BV(pin); // 1 tactDuration = 125ns
    asm("nop");
    asm("nop");
    asm("nop");
    asm("nop");
    asm("nop"); // 0.75mks

    PORTB &= ~_BV(pin); // 1 tactDuration
    asm("nop");
    asm("nop");
    asm("nop"); // 0.5mks
}

void setBitLow(byte pin) {
    PORTB |= _BV(pin); // 1 tactDuration
    asm("nop");
    asm("nop"); // 0.375mks

    PORTB &= ~_BV(pin); // 1 tactDuration
    asm("nop");
    asm("nop");
    asm("nop");
    asm("nop");
    asm("nop");
    asm("nop"); // 0.875mks
}

void trueByte(byte pin, byte intensity) {
    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
        intensity & _BV(i) ? setBitHigh(pin) : setBitLow(pin);
    }
}
void falseByte(byte pin) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        setBitLow(pin);
    }
}

void setPixel(byte pin, rgb color) {
    DDRB |= _BV(pin);

    color.g > 0 ? trueByte(pin, color.g) : falseByte(pin);
    color.r > 0 ? trueByte(pin, color.r) : falseByte(pin);
    color.b > 0 ? trueByte(pin, color.b) : falseByte(pin);
}
```

working well code:

```
void display(byte matrix[WIDTH][HEIGHT]) {
    for (byte rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < WIDTH; rowIdx++) {
        for (byte cellIdx = 0; cellIdx < HEIGHT; cellIdx++) {
            setPixel(LED, {matrix[rowIdx][cellIdx], 0, 0});
        }
    }
}

byte m[WIDTH][HEIGHT] = {
    { 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    { 0, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    { 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
...
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0},
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15}
};

int main() {
    display(m);
}
```

result:
[image]

NOT working well code:

```
void display(rgb matrix[WIDTH][HEIGHT]) {
    for (byte rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < WIDTH; rowIdx++) {
        for (byte cellIdx = 0; cellIdx < HEIGHT; cellIdx++) {
            setPixel(LED, matrix[rowIdx][cellIdx]);
        }
    }
}

rgb m[WIDTH][HEIGHT] = {
    {
            {15, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0}
    },
...
};


int main() {
    display(m);
}
```

result:
[image]

I will be glad to any advice...

Comment: BTW this code `color.g > 0 ? trueByte(pin, color.g) : falseByte(pin);` can be simplified to this `trueByte(pin, color.g)`. If the colour is zero then `trueByte` does exactly the same as `falseByte`.

Comment: What is `LED` in setpixel defined? Do you have a logic analyzer to check what's send to the led matrix, are you sure it's not a timing issue?

Comment: @alagner, `LED` is `PB0`, I haven\`t any analyzer(. I guess it is timing issue, because green leds are quite similar with red expected, but I have no idea, where a time shift is and why it depends on struct (btw, if I use array[3] for rgb storing, and use it to build a struct, it doesn\`t work too)

Comment: Can you show your full avr-gcc command? I mean optimization level mostly. BTW what is the protocol between the AVR and LEDs? Some sort of Manchester code?

Comment: @alagner, I\`m not sure where I can find it... I use CLion + platrofm.io plugin to upload it (it uses avrdude to upload code).

Comment: About the protocol: I found it on youtube, there was 0.8mks (+/- 125ns) HIGH + 0.45mks (+/- 125ns) LOW for TRUE and 0.4mks (+/-125ns) HIGH + 0.85mks (+/- 125ns) for FALSE